# Visual Studio Code User Defined Argument

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working with visual studio code tasks and can define arguments in a task successfully upfront as follows:

```
{"version":"0.1.0","command":"example","isShellCommand":true,"tasks":
[{"taskName":"example task","suppressTaskName":true,"args":["examplearg"]}]}
```

I would like to be able to type in the argument when running the task, as the argument needs to be user defined, is that possible? For example I would like to be able to Run Task from command pallete: example task --myCustomArg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Open an issue in [their repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues) and see what they say.

There is, however, a way to pass the current file. [See here.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_variables-in-tasksjson)

Your last choice would be to create an extension. You should give it a try as well.

Comment: I am making an extension, it actually already creates the tasks.json file. As I'm thinking about that and your response, I'm thinking I can have another action, that updates a variable in the extension and/or updates the tasks.json file, so that should be doable. Is there a way to pass an argument from the command palette into the extension action? That might not be stated very clearly, I'm going to dig into that.

Comment: "Is there a way to pass an argument from the command palette into the extension action?" I believe that yes you can do that. Just not to the built-in task-runner.

Comment: Having trouble finding a way to do this, I define my extension commands in the package.json file, the title of this definition is what I use in the command pallet to call the action from extensions.js. To my knowledge there is no way to enter an argument at this step so I am at a loss how I would get any user input (like a string) into my extensions action. The closest workaround I can think of is letting the user edit the tasks.json file entering the arguments they want, but this is not really what I am trying to accomplish. Any pointers?