# Is it possible to pass arguments to a task in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Here's an example of my `tasks.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "test",
      "suppressTaskName": true,
      "command": "python",
      "args": [
        "tests/brewer_tests.py"
      ],
      "isTestCommand": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I can run this with `shift+cmd+alt+b`. I can also run it with `alt+t`, and choose it from the menu. Is it possible to pass additional arguments in that menu? e.g.
[image]

And you could build it into your task like so:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "test",
      "suppressTaskName": true,
      "command": "python",
      "args": [
        "tests/brewer_tests.py",
        $arg1                        # would resolve to "ARG1"
      ],
      "isTestCommand": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Or something similar?

Comment: Looks like no, but there's a Github issue for it, so vote on it: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1574

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code User Defined Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382899/visual-studio-code-user-defined-argument)

Answer (score 101):

I used the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50952101/3182091) until now, but since Visual Studio Code has now an [official support for task prompts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables) I will add it as an answer here.

In your tasks.json file, you add the key `inputs` next to your `tasks`. This key contains an array with all possible parameters. Note that not every task has to use all of these inputs.
All of these inputs have an `id`, which you will use to reference the input in your task.
Now, in the task you only need to add `${input:myInputId}` whereever you need the parameter.

Example:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Echo param",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo ${input:param1}",
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Echo without param",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo Hello",
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "param1",
            "description": "Param1:",
            "default": "Hello",
            "type": "promptString"
        },
    ]
}
```

The task `Echo param` will open a prompt, which lets you input a string value and it will then print this value. The task `Echo without param` will simply print "Hello".

Answer (score 9):

Here's what is working for me for now - using this to run a `golang` snippet with custom arguments.
If you add a keyboard mapping to this, the process is very straightforward.

So far tested this only under Windows - linux version is commented out for that reason

```
{
        "label": "runwithargs",
        "type": "shell",
        "windows": {
            "options": {
                "shell": {
                    "executable": "powershell.exe",
                    "args": [
                        "-NoProfile",
                        "-ExecutionPolicy",
                        "Bypass",
                        "-Command"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "command": "",
            "args": [
                { "value": "$cmdargs = read-host 'Enter command line arguments';", "quoting": "weak"},
                { "value": "go run ${file} $cmdargs", "quoting": "weak"}
            ]
        },
        /*"linux": {
            "command": "echo 'Enter command line arguments: '; read cmdargs;",
            "args": [ "go run ${file} $cmdargs" ]                
        },*/          
        "presentation": {
            "panel": "dedicated",
            "focus": true
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have been looking for this for a while now. This solution seems to work pretty good. You can also prompt for multiple arguments, by simply chaining them like this:
`$arg1 = read-host 'Arg 1:';$arg2 = read-host 'Arg 2:'`
Only drawback I found so far is, that vs code does not like the `{"value": "", "quoting": "weak" `-syntax.

Comment: @Springrbua This should be added to the base task configuration, right? But still "value" fields inside "args" are incorrect type. It is quite unclear how to apply this answer. I have VS code 1.25.1

Comment: @BenceKaulics you can realy just paste this into your tasks. Json File. Then replace the value of the 2nd "value" field with the command you want to execute. As I said, VS code gives a warning, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding [Input variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables), [VSCode 1.43 (Feb. 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#promptstring-password-input) adds a new feature:

> ### promptString Password Input
>
> The "`promptString`" "`input`" type can have `"password": true`, which **will cause the quick input that shows to obscure the typed content like a password**.

Answer (score 0):

### Create a VsCode task to Git Clone with LF end of line characters

Open the directory (File/Open Folder) in VsCode where you want to clone a repository.
Use `Ctrl+P` to open the user `task.json` file, copy the JSON below and paste it into the `task.json` file.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "CloneGitRepoLF",
            "type": "shell",
            "windows": {
                "options": {
                    "shell": {
                        "executable": "powershell.exe",
                        "args": [
                            "-NoProfile",
                            "-ExecutionPolicy",
                            "Bypass",
                            "-Command"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "command": "",
                "args": [
                    { "value": "$cmdargs = read-host 'Enter the Git repo to clone';", "quoting": "weak"},
                    { "value": "wsl git clone --config core.autocrlf=false $cmdargs", "quoting": "weak"}
                ]
            },
            "presentation": {
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "focus": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can then run the task named `CloneGitRepoLF`.

### Getting fancy

Install the `Task Buttons` extension. Search VsCode for `settings.json`. Add the following to the JSON:

```s
"VsCodeTaskButtons.tasks": [
    {
        "label": "$(github) Clone Git Repo LF",
        "task": "CloneGitRepoLF",
        "tooltip": "This is task ensures Git clones the repo with LF EOL."
    }
],
```

You should now have a button at the very bottom of the VsCode window, named `Clone Git Repo LF` that you can use as a shortcut to clone a repository.

Comment: what if i dont want to manully ad any input and have default input that will automatically used?