# VSCode Tasks, user input for npm script

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am trying to create a task for the **npm script configured** in **package.json**. So, here are the files:

**package.json**

```
....
scripts : {
    "migrate": "node_modules/.bin/migrate-mongo",
    "migrate:create": "npm run migrate create" // --> this command needs input (file name)
}
....
```

Now when I have to run the **migrate:create** command I have to go to shell and run like this:

```
$> npm run migrate:craete filename
```

And it works fine.

Now I want to create a task for the same. For that I did some research and taking the idea from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53846572/1227940 created the **tasks.json as**:

**tasks.json**

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "Create a db migration script.",
      "command": "npm run migrate create ${input:migrationName}",
      
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "type": "promptString",
      "id": "migrationName",
      "description": "Name your migration script?",
      "default": "create"
    }
  ]
}
```

But somehow it is not giving me a text box to input anything and directly going inside and firing a command: **npm run migrate:create** which is failing since filename is missed.

Can anyone please shed some light, what I lacked and what I missed, please let me know?

Thanks in advance,
happy coding :)

Comment: Do you need this extension? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=augustocdias.tasks-shell-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I did some research and found the solution and here it is:

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "Create Migration Script",
            "command": "npm run migrate:create ${input:migrationName}",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "type": "promptString",
            "id": "migrationName",
            "description": "Name your migration script (prefix with create-, update-, delete-, insert-)?"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here the command is the actual script I configured in **pacakage.json** as:

**package.json**

```
....
scripts : {
    "migrate": "node_modules/.bin/migrate-mongo",
    "migrate:create": "npm run migrate create",
}
....
```

In the command of tasks.json I mentioned the **npm run script** which is configured in **package.json**.

Thanks and happy coding :)