# Debug Command line in Visual Studio code

Tags: c++, c, command-line, visual-studio-debugging

I am now using Visual studio code and I want to debug C/C++ program which runs as a command line. However, debug of Visual studio code just supports the normal program (not a command line program). When I want to debug a command line program, I need to edit my code in which I initialize the argument before running debugger. 
For example

```
int main(int argv, char *argc[])
{
    if (argv != 2)
    {
        printf("Wrong syntax\nCorrect Syntax: readfile <source file>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen(argc[1], "rb");
}
```

When I want to debug, I need to initialize like this:

```
int main()
{
    /*if (argv != 2)
    {
        printf("Wrong syntax\nCorrect Syntax: readfile <source file>\n");
        exit(1);
    }*/ //eliminate this part
    argc[1] = "phonebook.dat";
    FILE *fp = fopen(argc[1], "rb");
```

I find it annoying. So how do I change the debugger on VS code to debug C and C++ command line programs?

Comment: What is "the normal program"? And what do you need to edit?

Comment: @Gerhardh I have edited it, read it again please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging with command-line parameters in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio)

Comment: What is "not a command line program"? Every program takes a command line. Whether it uses the parameters or opens a GUI or not is a different story.

Comment: @kaylum Do you see that I am using Visual STUDIO CODE?

Comment: Apologies, I did miss that. But have you tried searching "pass command line arguments to visual studio code"? Such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382899/visual-studio-code-user-defined-argument) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45582698/is-it-possible-to-pass-arguments-to-a-task-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Did you try to add `args` to the launch configuration? For details see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: @kaylum it doesn't help because it works for another language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your configuration to receive command line arguments.

See this: [Configuring launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_args)